# Merge value of a list of tuple

Tags: python

I have a task to read line by line in a large gzip file (> 1G) and then push raw data as messages to RabbitMQ. The value for a single field (in this case Synonyms) can be lay on different lines. So I read line by line map each line as a message and then reduce by the key (in this case the letter 'A')

So I have a list of tuple like this

```
a = [('ctdbase-0.1', 'disease', 'A', 'synonyms', ['A']), ('ctdbase-0.1', 'disease', 'A', 'synonyms', ['a'])]
```

How can I merge the value of Synonyms

The result that I expected look like this

```
a = [('ctdbase-0.1', 'disease', 'A', 'synonyms', ['A', 'a'])]
```

I know I can do something like this in Dict but I can't use Dict in here
Many thanks!!!

Comment: Do all the tuples in your list only differ in the last element?

Comment: Yes they do ....!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
>>> a[0][:-1] + (sum((x[-1] for x in a), []),)
('ctdbase-0.1', 'disease', 'A', 'synonyms', ['A', 'a'])
```

This assumes that all your tuples only differ in the last element. It takes the first n-1 values from the first tuple and adds all the last-element-lists together to create a single list. Finally, these sub-results are concatenated.

Your expected result wraps my result in a list such that you end up with a single-element list. I don't see why that would be necessary.

Comment: @QSnake no problem. Your question would have been better if you include some of your own attempts. Remember that for the next one, please.

Comment: OK, I'll do that in the furture.

Comment: I have a task to read line by line in a large gzip file (> 1G) and then push raw data as messages to RabbitMQ. The value for a single field (in this case Synonyms) can be lay on different lines. So I read line by line map each line as a message and then reduce by the key (in this case the letter 'A')

Comment: I used to use Spark (PySpark) for this task. but my boss is not allowed me to use Spark anymore, but pure python instead. So basically I'm trying to apply the Map-Reduce from Spark :)

Comment: @QSnake you can edit that info into your question, it's more visible there. Also if the question is solved consider accepting the answer, thanks.